# Verify signature

Tags: java, sha1, signature

I have 64bit encoded signature
need to verify SHA1

this is what I did

```
byte[] decodeValue = Base64.decode(currentItem.getEnclosure().getSignature(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and I got byte results

now signature

```
try {

 Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");

    if(signature.verify(decodeValue)){
... ...

   }catch (Exception e){
    Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());
   }
```

I always got this exception **Signature object is not initialized properly**

How to resolve this

Comment: Have you read the docs for the exception and verified that your input is correctly encoded? ["the passed-in signature is improperly encoded or of the wrong type"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html#verify(byte[]))

Answer (score 1):

To verify the signature, you must:

1. initialize the Signature object with the certificate of the issuer,
2. call update() with all the bytes of the message,
3. call verify() with the bytes of the signature

Comment: where is the signature?

Comment: It should be init with X509 cert.